# Are there any tag matching algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, tags

My system is similar to stackoverflow. Basically, a post can have multiple tags, and there is a search function that find posts with matching query's tags (all tags must be matched)

I wonder if are there any algorithms/ data structure that solve the problem of post tagging/ searching efficiently? Which one is the most efficient in term of speed (time complexity)?

Comment: "Inverted Indexes" Can be useful. "and Mostly you will have a separate tags table and then individual posts can have multiple tags linked (using keys)" is widely used approach as @abhinav described.

Answer (score 2):

In past i haven't used any specialized DS for this. Infact, if you want to do this with RDBMS, kindly read details of [how Wordpress do this using taxanomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). Mostly you will have a separate tags table and then indivisual posts can have multiple tags linked (using keys).

Another popular approach is to look at your problem as a facetting problem. You must use a full-text indexing framework and develop your facetted browsing on top of that. [Here is an excellent post from the creator of Lucene/Solr](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/faceted-search-solr) which explains this very case. With facetted browsing in place, you will be able to display something what stackoverflow does:

```
algorithm × 21165
search × 8863
data-structures × 5867
tags × 2886
stackoverflow × 721
```

Answer (score 0):

The most time-efficient way of storing this kind of data for searching is usually within an [Inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). This also happens to be what the most common search engines/information retrieval systems are built around.

For an actual implementation of this, I suggest you have a look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org).